# dslContract generated from spring restdocs not working with queryParameters

Tags: spring-cloud, wiremock

When i create dslcontracts in my restdoc test with query parameters, it creates the groovy contract file as well as stub file. But when i deploy the contract using @EnableStubRunnerServer, i can never get the query parameters to match.

I realized that the stub file is generated with request looking like:

```
"request" : {
    "url" : "/search",
    "method" : "GET",
    "queryParameters" : {
      "query" : {
        "equalTo" : "friday"
      }
    }
  }

However if i change the stub file to :

"request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/search",
    "method" : "GET",
    "queryParameters" : {
      "query" : {
        "equalTo" : "friday"
      }
    }
  }
it seems to work. Is there a way to make this work?

Here is how i'm writing the test:

@Test
public void searchWithQuery() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("query", "equalTo(\"friday\")");

    mockMvc.perform(get(SEARCH_PATH + "?query=friday"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("search-query",
                    dslContract(param)
            ));
 }
```

Comment: Most likely it's a bug, can you file it please?

Comment: Just created a bug report : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1077